# Export and Import apacheds data into LDIF programmatically from java

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds, ldif

I have create a server in Apache Directory Studio. I also created a partition and inserted some entries to that server form Java. Now I want to Backup and Restore this data in and LDIF file programmatically. I am new to LDAP. So please show me a detailed way to Export and Import entries programmatically using java from my server into LDIF.

#### Current solution:

Now I am using this approach to backup:

```
  EntryCursor cursor = connection.search(new Dn("o=partition"), "(ObjectClass=*)", SearchScope.SUBTREE, "*", "+"); 
  Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  Path filePath = Paths.get("src/main/resources", "backup.ldif");
  BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath, charset);
  String st = ""; 
  
  while (cursor.next()) { 
    Entry entry = cursor.get();
    String ss = LdifUtils.convertToLdif(entry);
    st += ss + "\n";
  }
  writer.write(st);
  writer.close();
```

For restore I am using this:

```
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath);
  LdifReader entries = new LdifReader(is);
  
  for (LdifEntry ldifEntry : entries) {
    Entry entry = ldifEntry.getEntry();
    
    AddRequest addRequest = new AddRequestImpl();
    addRequest.setEntry(entry);
    addRequest.addControl(new ManageDsaITImpl());

    AddResponse res = connection.add(addRequest);
  }
```

But I am not sure whether this is the correct way.

#### Problem of this solution:

When I backup my database, it writes entries into LDIF in a random way, so restore does not works until I fix the order of entries manually. I there any better way? Please someone help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long search, I actually understand that the solution of restore the entries is a simple recursion. In backup procedure does not print the entries in random way, it maintain the tree order. So a simple recursion can order the entries well. Here is a sample code which I use-

```
void findEntry(LdapConnection connection, Entry entry, StringBuilder sb)
    throws LdapException, CursorException {
  sb.append(LdifUtils.convertToLdif(entry));
  sb.append("\n");
  EntryCursor cursor = connection.search(entry.getDn(), "(ObjectClass=*)", SearchScope.ONELEVEL, "*", "+");
  while (cursor.next()) {
    findEntry(connection, cursor.get(), sb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you tagged as Java and so look at the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html) or as you are using APacheDS, why not look at the [Apache LDAP API](https://directory.apache.org/api/downloads.html)

Either of them will work. I currently use [UnboundID LDAP SDK] which have [LDIF specific APIs].[3](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldif/package-frame.html). I assume [Apache LDAP API] does also, But I have not used them.

Comment: I am using eclipse and jetty.

Comment: Both of of the SDKs I mentioned are for Java. They should work fine with Eclipse and Jetty.